# Laravel webpack unable to locate Mix file

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack

Trying to use versioning and i get this error .

```
Unable to locate Mix file: /core/public/css/app.css. (View: C:\laragon\www\project\core\resources\views\master.blade.php)
```

My webpack.mix.js file

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');


mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').extract(['vue']);
   mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

   if (mix.inProduction()) {
      mix.version();
  }
```

header

```
<link href="{{ mix('/core/public/css/app.css', '/core/public') }}" rel="preload" as="style"
    onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
<script src="{{ mix('/core/public/js/manifest.js'), '/core/public'}}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('/core/public/js/vendor.js'), '/core/public' }}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('/core/public/js/app.js'), '/core/public' }}"></script>
```

mix-manifest.json output

```
{
    "/js/app.js": "/js/app.js?id=170c03d22dcc6f5e5936",
    "/css/app.css": "/css/app.css?id=3306ee8f312fb58dd115",
    "/js/manifest.js": "/js/manifest.js?id=41f053ba9a94d81b39f8",
    "/js/vendor.js": "/js/vendor.js?id=cf78339b219ecdecb320"
}
```

File structure inside project is

```
core
└───public
│   │   mix-manifest.json
│   │
│   └───js
│       │   app.js
│       │   manifest.js
│       │   vendor.js
│       |
|       css
|       |   app.css 
|       |
|
|
|
|''' 
└───webpack.mix.js
|...
```

Pointing to the javascript file like that

```
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

gives me an error

```
The Mix manifest does not exist. (View: C:\laragon\www\project\core\resources\views\master.blade.php) (View: C:\laragon\www\project\core\resources\views\master.blade.php)
```

Trying raw URL instead gives me this error

```
<script src="/css/app.css"></script>

GET https://project.test/css/app.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

The above file is located inside /core/public/css folder and it does not point correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This made it work

```
 <link href="{{ mix('css/app.css', 'core/public') }}" rel="preload" as="style"
        onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js', 'core/public') }}" defer></script>
```

To explain, the second parameter points to where the mix-manifest.json file exists.

Comment: I see, your problem is that you have moved the files, instead of having `root/public` you have `root/core/public` right ? Do not do that, no need to recreate the wheel as laravel works well without those changes.

Comment: I didn't create the project, i picked it up as it is, i completely agree with you. Otherwise development can be confusing following the documentation sometimes, for me as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are adding the root folder to your `mix` path... Do not do that, it is relative to your `root/public`...

You should have it like this:

```html
<link href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}" rel="preload" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
<script src="{{ mix('/js/manifest.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('/js/vendor.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#vendor-extraction)

Comment: I get an error The Mix manifest does not exist if i try it like that.

Comment: Share the error, but also try raw url instead of `mix`, so try `<script src="/js/manifest.js"></script>` (with each one) and see if that works.

Comment: Updated the question, using it without mix the versioning won't work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was accidentally using the `mix()` helper to reference a custom CSS file that I wasn't compiling with Laravel Mix. This can be fixed by either adding the file to `webpack.mix.js` to minify and compile it with the rest of the build files, or by using the `asset()` helper to reference it statically instead.